# Adding multiple configuration files to an application

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

HI,
I need to add multiple configuration files in my application. What is the easiest way to read a key value from these files? Currently I am using xmldocument class and select the node using an xpath expression. Is there any other simple way to do this in C# 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar need and found this to be extremely useful and simple.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs_ini.aspx
It is an INI file reader and writer, you just specify the header tag and the item name and it will read or write from a file.  It gives you strings and you can cast them with some try blocks.

INI is really a much simpler format than XML if you have less than fifty config options and they are not nested.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hacky solution would be to read all of the configuration files into one in memory document then use xpath to select the right nodes.

You've tagged this as c# 2.0, do you have access to LINQ to XML? That can make your queries a lot neater.

Comment: Sorry I won't be able to use LINQ. I think LINQ is integrated with ,net 3.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this could be to write a class that provides you with the information you need and serialize the object trough the XmlSerializer class. To load configuration information you can deserialize the resulting Xml back to an instance trough the XmlSerializer class.